# angular2 unit testing with dependent services

Tags: unit-testing, angular, angular2-services

I'm new to angular2 and trying to write tests for services. I have a userservice in my application which is a dependent service on multiple other services and params. The user service is making an rest-api call in the backend to pull user information.

I'm having a hard time to understand what is the correct way to inject the dependent services to this user service, so it can make a http call and get response.

user-service.ts

```
export class UserService extends HttpService {

private _authToken: string;
private _persistent: boolean;

constructor(http: Http, private sessionService: SessionService, private router: Router) {
    super(http);
    this._authToken = localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN_KEY);
}

get authToken(): string {
    return this._authToken;
}
```

session-service.ts

```
export class SessionService extends HttpService {

constructor(http: Http) {
    super(http);
    this.rootUrl = Constants.API_ROOT;
}

addSession(authToken: string, persistent:boolean=false): Observable<any> {
    return this.post(SESSIONS_ROOT, {persistent: persistent}, TokenService.AuthHeader(authToken));
}
```

user-service.spec.ts

```
 describe(' #######  User Service Test Cases  ####### ', () =>  beforeEach(() => {
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  providers: [
    // {
    //   provide: Router, 
    //   useClass: class { navigate = jasmine.createSpy("navigate")},  
    // },
    BaseRequestOptions,
    MockBackend,
    {
      provide: Http,
      useFactory: (backend: MockBackend, defaultOptions: BaseRequestOptions) => {
        return new Http(backend, defaultOptions);
      },
      deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions],
    },
    SessionService,
    UserService
  ],
  imports: [RouterTestingModule]
});   });   it('test method', inject([UserService], (userService: UserService) => {
    expect(userService.isEmailAvailable('a@a.com')).toBe('true');
 }));
```

});

But, I'm getting error when executing.

> #######  User Service Test Cases  #######
>       ×should return response when email is already subsribed
>           Expected AnonymousSubject({ _isScalar: false, observers: [  ], closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, thrownError: null, destination: AnonymousSubject({ _isScalar: false, observers: [  ], closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, thrownError: null, destination: AnonymousSubject({ _isScalar: false, observers: [  ], closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, thrownError: null, destination: ReplaySubject({ _isScalar: false, observers: [  ], closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, thrownError: null, scheduler: undefined, _events: [  ], _bufferSize: 1, _windowTime: Infinity }), source: ReplaySubject({ _isScalar: false, observers: [  ], closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, thrownError: null, scheduler: undefined, _events: [  ], _bufferSize: 1, _windowTime: Infinity }), operator: TakeOperator({ total: 1 }) }), source: AnonymousSubject({ _isScalar: false, observers: [  ], closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, thrownError: null, destination: ReplaySubject({ _isScalar: false, observers: [  ], closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, thrownError: null, scheduler: undefined, _events: [  ], _bufferSize: 1, _windowTime: Infinity }), source: ReplaySubject({ _isScalar: false, observers: [  ], closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, thrownError: null, scheduler: undefined, _events: [  ], _bufferSize: 1, _windowTime: Infinity }), operator: TakeOperator({ total: 1 }) }), operator: MapOperator({ project: Function, thisArg: undefined }) }), source: AnonymousSubject({ _isScalar: false, observers: [  ], closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, thrownError: null, destination: AnonymousSubject({ _isScalar: false, observers: [  ], closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, thrownError: null, destination: ReplaySubject({ _isScalar: false, observers: [  ], closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, thrownError: null, scheduler: undefined, _events: [  ], _bufferSize: 1, _windowTime: Infinity }), source: ReplaySubject({ _isScalar: false, observers: [  ], closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, thrownError: null, scheduler: undefined, _events: [  ], _bufferSize: 1, _windowTime: Infinity }), operator: TakeOperator({ total: 1 }) }), source: AnonymousSubject({ _isScalar: false, observers: [  ], closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, thrownError: null, destination: ReplaySubject({ _isScalar: false, observers: [  ], closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, thrownError: null, scheduler: undefined, _events: [  ], _bufferSize: 1, _windowTime: Infinity }), source: ReplaySubject({ _isScalar: false, observers: [  ], closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, thrownError: null, scheduler: undefined, _events: [  ], _bufferSize: 1, _windowTime: Infinity }), operator: TakeOperator({ total: 1 }) }), operator: MapOperator({ project: Function, thisArg: undefined }) }), operator: CatchOperator({ selector: Function, caught:  }) }) to be 'true'.
>               at webpack:///src/app/test/user.spec.ts:75:69 <- config/karma-test-shim.js:87887:71 [ProxyZone]

I'm not sure what to understand from the error. Any help on how to proceed or inject dependent services correctly and create there instances will be help. 
Thank you so much. Appreciate the help.